# Train NER model in Stanford NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Exception while executing Train the model. Please find the steps that I have followed to train NER model,

**Step1** : Create the training file like,

```
the 0
Greenland   LOC
whale   0
is  0
deposed 0
,   0
-   0
the 0
great   0
sperm   0
whale   0
now 0
reigneth    0
!   0
```

and save as "TrainingFile.tsv" file.

**Step2:** Created a .prop file we could use to train the first classifier.

Custom-ner.prop:

```
trainFile = TrainingFile.tsv
serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1
maxLeft=1
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

Step3: Build the classifier by executing the below code,

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier \
-prop propforclassifierone.prop
```

**While perform the Step3 throws an exception like,**

Exception :

```
useSequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useTypeySequences=true
useDisjunctive=true
noMidNGrams=true
serializeTo=ner-model.ser.gz
maxNGramLeng=6
useNGrams=true
usePrev=true
useNext=true
maxLeft=1
trainFile=directories2-10combined.tsv
map=word=0,answer=1
useWord=true
useTypeSeqs=true
=\
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileN
otFoundException: directories2-10combined.tsv (The system cannot find the file s
pecified)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.inputStreamFromFile(IOUtils.java:509)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromFile(IOUtils.java:550)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setN
extObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:189)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.<ini
t>(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:161)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ResettableReaderIteratorFactory.iterator(
ResettableReaderIteratorFactory.java:98)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.j
ava:414)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:253)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper.iterator(ObjectBankWrapp
er.java:45)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.train(CRFClassifier.java:1585)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequence
Classifier.java:758)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequence
Classifier.java:746)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3034)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: directories2-10combined.tsv (The syste
m cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.inputStreamFromFile(IOUtils.java:503)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you are using the correct files?

In your example in Step 2 you have a properties file called `Custom-ner.prop`, while in Step 3 you call a command with a file called `propforclassifierone.prop`. 
Also, your training file seems to be named differently: `TrainingFile.tsv` vs. `directories2-10combined.tsv`.

Plus, make sure, your training file is in your class path (respective in the same directory as the jar file) or provide the absolute path of your training file.